# how solve about count distinct group by mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a problem  about distinct and group by, please help me

```
KTP            KECAMATAN          
1111111        PARIAMAN
1111111        PARIAMAN
2222222        PAYAKUMBUH
1111111        PAYAKUMBUH
```

i want Result like this

```
KECAMATAN        KTP        TOTAL
PARIAMAN         1111111    2
PAYAKUMBUH       1111111    1
PAYAKUMBUH       2222222    1


select KTP, KECAMATAN, COUNT(distinct KTP) as TOTAL 
from TABLE_A 
group by kecamatan
```

Comment: In this case you don't need distinct, if you do county+group by it will take distinct since the required column is outside the count. What result are you getting with the current code?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT KTP, KECAMATAN, COUNT(KECAMATAN) as TOTAL
FROM TABLE_A 
GROUP BY KTP,KECAMATAN;
```